# Erro ao usar HAVING em consulta com data/hora

Tags: sql, query

Tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
 SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY V.DATA ASC) AS ID,
    V.CHAPA AS CHAPA,
    F.NOME  AS NOME,
    V.DATA  AS DATA,
    CASE WHEN V.BATIDA IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE V.BATIDA END AS IS_NULL
        FROM
            ARELBATIDATRANSITOVIEW AS V
            LEFT JOIN V_DADOSFUNC  AS F ON V.CHAPA = F.CHAPA
      WHERE
          V.CHAPA = 2311 
            GROUP BY V.CHAPA,V.DATA,F.NOME,V.BATIDA
                HAVING IS_NULL = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
              ORDER BY DATA ASC
```

Esta retornando a seguinte mensagem:

> Mensagem 207, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 42 Invalid column name
>   'IS_NULL'.

Comment: tá correto `IS_NULL `? não seria `is null` ??

Comment: is_null foi só o nome que eu dei para a coluna, mais qualquer nome que colocar da erro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependendo do banco de dados que você está usando, você não consegue utilizar no `HAVING` uma coluna que está sendo criada no `SELECT`

Uma alternativa seria:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY V.DATA ASC) AS ID,
    V.CHAPA AS CHAPA,
    F.NOME  AS NOME,
    V.DATA  AS DATA,
    CASE WHEN V.BATIDA IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE V.BATIDA END AS IS_NULL
FROM
    ARELBATIDATRANSITOVIEW AS V
LEFT JOIN V_DADOSFUNC  AS F ON V.CHAPA = F.CHAPA
WHERE
    V.CHAPA = 2311 
GROUP BY V.CHAPA,V.DATA,F.NOME,V.BATIDA
HAVING 
    CASE WHEN V.BATIDA IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE V.BATIDA END = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
ORDER BY DATA ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito queesteja faltando o apelido no `IS_NULL`. Por exemplo:

```
a.IS_NULL
```

Comment: Não deu, Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Resultado final:

```
 SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY V.DATA ASC) AS ID,
    V.CHAPA AS CHAPA,
    F.NOME  AS NOME,
    V.DATA  AS DATA,
    isnull(V.BATIDA, 0 ) as TBATIDA
FROM
 ARELBATIDATRANSITOVIEW AS V
 LEFT JOIN V_DADOSFUNC  AS F ON V.CHAPA = F.CHAPA
WHERE V.CHAPA = 2311  
AND isnull(V.BATIDA, 0 )='1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
  ORDER BY DATA ASC
```